# How to periodically check if STDIN is open?

Tags: shell, file-descriptors

Some programs will exit when their `STDIN` is closed. Those that do this work nicely with Erlang/Elixir supervision via "ports".

For those that don't, [the Elixir docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html#module-zombie-os-processes) suggest this wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wrapper.sh
"$@" &
pid=$!
while read line ; do
  :
done
kill -KILL $pid
```

This allows calling `wrapper.sh my_script arg1 arg2`. `wrapper.sh` starts and backgrounds the specified program, and when `wrapper.sh`'s `STDIN` is closed, its blocking `read` finishes and it terminates the backgrounded process.

This approach has a downside, however; **if the backgrounded process terminates for some other reason, `wrapper.sh` doesn't notice**, and therefore neither does Erlang/Elixir.

I'd like to modify this script to do the following:

In a loop:

- If `STDIN` is closed, kill `$pid`
- If `$pid` is dead, exit
- Otherwise, sleep briefly

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `$pid` is dead like so:

```bsh
while kill -0 $pid >/dev/null; do
    # $pid is still alive
done

# $pid is dead or you lack permissions to send signals to it
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is `dash`/`busybox`, `ksh93` or `zsh`, you could set a trap on `SIGCHLD`:

```
#! /bin/sh
trap exit CHLD
"$@" &
while read line; do :; done
kill $!
wait
```

This will exit as soon as the `"$@" &` process has exited or the `read` has got an `EOF`.

But `bash` has a nasty `read` built-in, which is [restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424823/10306503) in place when interrupted by a signal, so something clunkier is needed. You can arrange for the background process to send a terminating signal to its parent upon exiting:

```
#! /bin/sh
{ "$@"; kill $$; } &
while read line; do :; done
pkill -P $!
kill $!
wait
```

This will have to waste another process to wait for the `"$@"` command, and use the `-P` (parent pid) selector of `pkill` since `$!` no longer refer to the `"$@"` command, but to its parent. The extra `kill $!` is still needed in case the `"$@"` happens to be a built-in. Notice that there's no job control in scripts; all processes (including those started with `&`) run in the same process group.

You can use `p/kill -KILL` everywhere if a `TERM` signal isn't enough.

Another, even clunkier workaround that only works with newer (>= 4.0) versions of bash is to use the nonstandard `-t` (timeout) option of `read` and exploit the fact that `read` will return 1 upon `EOF` and a status > 128 upon timeout:

```
#! /bin/bash
"$@" &
while :; do
        read -t 1 line
        case $? in
        0)      ;;
        1)      kill $!; wait; exit;;
        *)      kill -0 $! || exit;;
        esac
done 2>/dev/null
```

This somehow seems to work with `mksh`, too.

Comment: This is helpful! Note that the different return values for `read` on timeout vs `EOF` match what I see in `help read` in Bash 5.0.2, but in Bash 3.2 there is no such distinction.